# Duplicate callback outputs which output id is unique

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Getting error message.

`Error message:`

```
Duplicate callback outputs

In the callback for output(s):
  mer_test.data
Output 0 (mer_test.data) is already in use. To resolve this, set `allow_duplicate=True` on duplicate outputs, or combine the outputs into one callback function, distinguishing the trigger by using `dash.callback_context` if necessary.
```

I had multiple `input` for one `output` and this pattern for multiple pages.
All the table `id` is unique with the same `children`.
However, keep on getting the same error message even tried to change the `id` name.

All the dropdown value is stored in the dcc.store.

**CODE**

`dropdown.py`

```
from .query import get_date


df = get_date()

year_cat = list(df['year'].unique())

corp_cat=[
    {'label': 'Corp A', 'value': 'corp1'},
    {'label': 'Corp B', 'value': 'corp2'},
    ]

top_cat = [
    {'label': '15', 'value': 15},
    {'label': '50', 'value': 50},
    {'label': '100', 'value': 100},
    ]




dropdown = dbc.Container ([
   dbc.Row([
       dbc.Col([
           html.H6('Year:'),
           dcc.Dropdown(id='year_dd', 
                        value= df['year'].max(),
                        options = [{'label':x, 'value':x} for x in year_cat],
                        searchable = True, 
                        search_value='',
                        placeholder= 'Please select ...',
                                                
                          ),
           
           ], width=3, md=3 ),
       
       
       dbc.Col([            
           html.H6('Month:'),
           
           dcc.Dropdown(id='month_dd', 
                        value= '',                         
                        searchable = True, 
                        search_value='',
                        placeholder= 'Please select ...',
                        className = 'mchanly-dropdown-list'
                         
                         ),
           html.Br(),
           
           ], width=3, md=3),
           
           
         dbc.Col([
           html.H6('Date:'),
           
             dcc.Dropdown(id='date_dd', 
                          value='',
                          searchable = True, 
                          search_value='',
                          placeholder= 'Please select ...',

                          ),
                 
             html.Br(),
             
             ], width=3, md=3),
         
         dbc.Col([
             html.H6('Corporation:'),
             
             dcc.Dropdown(id='meranly_corp_dd',
                          options=corp_cat,
                          value='tpa',
                          searchable = True, 
                          search_value='',
                          placeholder= 'Please select ...',
 
                          
                          ),
             ], width=3, md=3),
         
          
          
          
        
        ]),
    
    
    ])
    
    
 
top = dbc.Container ([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                    html.P('Top:'),
                    
                    dcc.Dropdown(id='top_dd',
                                 options=top_cat,
                                 value= 15,
                                 searchable = True, 
                                 search_value='',
                                 placeholder= 'Please select ...',
 
                                 ),
                    ]),
            ]),
    ])










@callback(
    Output('month_dd','options'),
    Input('year_dd', 'value')
    )


def update_dd (year_dd):
       
    year_month= df.drop_duplicates(['mthtyr'], inplace= False)
    
    relevant_month= year_month[ df['year'] == year_dd]['monthname'].values.tolist()

    month_option= [dict(label=x,value=x)for x in relevant_month]
    
    
    return month_option



@callback(
    Output('month_dd','value'),
    Input('month_dd', 'options')
    )


def default_value(latest_month):
    month_value = latest_month[-1]['value']
    
    return month_value



# #date dropdown based on filtered month
@callback(
    Output('date_dd','options'),
    Input('month_dd', 'value'),
    State('year_dd', 'value')
    )


def update_dd (month_dd, year_dd):
       
    month_date= df.drop_duplicates(['Date'], inplace= False)
    
    relevant_date= month_date[ (df['monthname'] == month_dd) & (df['year'] == year_dd)]['Date'].values.tolist()
    date_option= [dict(label=x,value=x)for x in relevant_date]
    
    
    return date_option



@callback(
    Output('date_dd','value'),
    Input('date_dd', 'options')
    )


def default_value(latest_date):
    date_value = latest_date[-1]['value']
    
    return date_value





@callback(
    Output('storedate','data'),
    Input('date_dd', 'value'),
    State('year_dd', 'value'),
    State('month_dd', 'value'),

    )


def stored_selected_value (date, year, month):
    return {'date': date, 'year': year, 'month': month} 




@callback(
    Output('storecorp','data'),
    Input('corp_dd', 'value'),

    )


def stored_selected_value (corp):
    
    return {'corp': corp} 




@callback(
    Output('storetop','data'),
    Input('top_dd', 'value'),

    )


def stored_selected_value (top):
    
    return {'top': top}
```

`store.py`

```
import dash_core_components as dcc



# Define the dcc.Store component
store = dcc.Store(id='storedate', storage_type='session')

corp_store = dcc.Store(id='storecorp', storage_type='session')

top_store = dcc.Store(id='storetop', storage_type='session')
```

`analysis.py`

```
from .pages.dropdown import dropdown, top
from .pages.nav import nav
from .pages.store import store,corp_store , top_store
from .pages.bestperform import best_perform



dash.register_page(__name__,
                   path='/testting',  # '/' is home page and it represents the url
                   name=' Analysis',  # name of page, commonly used as name of link
                   title='analysis',  # title that appears on browser's tab
                   icon="bi bi-clipboard-data",
)


require_login(__name__, 
              access_level= package2
              )



def layout():
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return html.Div(["Please ", dcc.Link("login", href="/login"), " to continue"])

    return dbc.Container ([
        mcht_store, 
        mcht_corp_store, 
        mcht_top_store,
           
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col ([
                html.H2 ('Analysis')
                ],width=12)
            ], className = ''),
        
        dbc.Row(dropdown, className = ''),
        
        dbc.Row(nav, className = ''),
        
        html.Hr(className = 'r'),
        
        dbc.Row(test1, className = ''),
        
        ])
```

`best_perform.py`

```
from .dropdown import top
from .query import get_best_perform
from .view import (
    comm_table,
    comm_header,
    comm_cell,
    cell_con1,
    comm_data_con,
    data_con1_green,
    data_con2_red,
    data_con3_orange,
    data_con4_grey,
    
    )




best_perform = dbc.Container([

    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            html.H5("BEST PERFORMANCE"),
            
            dbc.Row (top),
            
            
            dash_table.DataTable(id='mer_test', 
                                  columns=[
                                      {'name': 'ID', "id": 'id'},
                                      {'name': 'Registration Name', "id": 'registration_name'},
                                      {'name': 'Rank3', "id": 'rank3'},
                                      {'name': 'Last 3-mth', "id": 'lmtd3'},
                                      {'name': 'Rank2', "id": 'rank2'},
                                      {'name': 'Last 2-mth', "id": 'lmtd2'},
                                      {'name': 'Rank1', "id": 'rank1'},
                                      {'name': 'Last 1-mth', "id": 'lmtd'},
                                      {'name': 'This mth', "id": 'tmtd'},
                                      {'name': 'Diff(%)', "id": 'variance'},
                                      ],
                                    export_format='csv',
                                    export_headers='display',
                                    page_size= 50,
                                   
                                    style_table = comm_table(),
                                   
                                    style_header= comm_header(),
                                                                      
                                    style_cell=comm_cell(),
                                                                      
                                    style_cell_conditional = cell_con1(),
                                   
                                    style_data_conditional= comm_data_con() + data_con1_green() + 
                                         data_con2_red() + data_con3_orange()+ data_con4_grey(),
                                   
                                    ),
            
            ], className = '')
        ], className = ''), 
    
    html.Br(),html.Br(),html.Br()

    
    
    
    
    ])







@callback(
    [Output('mer_test', 'data')], 
    
    [
     Input('storedate','data'),
     Input('storecorp','data'),
     Input('storetop', 'data')
     ],

    )

    


def update_table1(selection, corp_selection, top_filter):
    if not selection or not corp_selection or not top_filter:
        return dash.no_update
    
    else:   
               
        selection = pd.to_datetime(selection['date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d')
        corp_selection = corp_selection['corp']
        top_filter = top_filter['top']
        
        dff = get_best_perform(selection, corp_selection)
        
        dff= dff.head(top_filter)
        
        dt = dff
        
        
        
        dt['tmtd']=dt['tmtd'].fillna(0)
        dt['lmtd']=dt['lmtd'].fillna(0)
        dt['lmtd2']=dt['lmtd2'].fillna(0)
        dt['lmtd3']=dt['lmtd3'].fillna(0)
        
        
        dt['variance'] = ((dt['tmtd'] - dt['lmtd']) / dt['lmtd']) * 100
        
        
        dt['rank2'] = dt['rank2'].fillna('-')
        dt['rank3'] = dt['rank3'].fillna('-')
        
        dt['variance'] = dt['variance'].apply(lambda x: float(x))
        dt['variance'] = dt['variance'].round()
        
        dt['tmtd']=dt['tmtd'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)
        dt['lmtd']=dt['lmtd'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)
        dt['lmtd2']=dt['lmtd2'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)
        dt['lmtd3']=dt['lmtd3'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)

       
        dt['variance']=dt['variance'].map('{:.0f}%'.format)
        dt['variance']=dt['variance'].replace('inf%', '-')
        

        columns = dt[['id', 'registration_name',
                        'rank3',
                        'lmtd3',
                        'rank2',
                        'lmtd2',
                        'rank1',
                        'lmtd',
                        'tmtd' ,
                        'variance'
                      ]]
        


        data= columns.to_dict('records')



       
        return data
```

---

I am testing 2 pattern and both are using the same content.

1. `app.py > analysis.py > best_perform.py`

```
if the website is go thru like this, will have error message :

 Duplicate callback outputs
In the callback for output(s):
  mer_test.data
Output 0 (mer_test.data) is already in use.
To resolve this, set `allow_duplicate=True` on
duplicate outputs, or combine the outputs into
one callback function, distinguishing the trigger
by using `dash.callback_context` if necessary.

app.py will act as master and link multiple page, 
so the analysis.py is one of the content, 
best_perform.py is one of the page under analysis.py
```

2. `app.py > page.py`

```
if the website is go thru like this, will not have the error message,
 and callback able to perform

app.py will have the content of the analysis.py (mentioned in previous pattern) 
and best_perform.py is one of the page
```

So. what is the reason cause the callback duplicate? Currently, only one callback.

Comment: Are you able to create a MWE raising the duplicate error? There is quite a lot of code here

Comment: What is MWE? How to generate? I'm new in this area.

Comment: a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) raising the error you encounter.